# server side redirect in classic ASP on IIS7

Tags: redirect, iis-7, asp-classic

I'm trying to implement a simple `301 redirect` from `mydomain.com/page1.asp` to `mydomain.com/page2.asp`. These are dynamically generated product pages of an ecommerce store, so they don't physically exist as files.

In Apache it's simple to do with `.htaccess` but all I found are ways to redirect *static* pages, that actually exist on the server, such as placing the code below in at the top of the existent file:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
<%
' Redirect to the new location with the correct 301 Moved Permanently status
Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location", "http://www.example.com/new-page.php"
%>
```

Is there a way to redirect a dynamically generated page in IIS7 using classic asp?

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments received, I need an URL rewrite module. @ZippyV suggested [this one](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)

Comment: I think you are looking to rewrite a url instead of redirecting. IIS has a rewrite module: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: If you really want to use Classic ASP then you can setup custom error pages in ASP and use Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer within conditional statements.  However It's much easier to usee the IIS rewrite module as ZippyV suggests above.  web.config on IIS 7 performs a similar role to .htaccess

Comment: thanks for the help, guys, @ZippyV, can you post an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to *rewrite* your URL requests instead of *redirecting* them.

IIS has a URL Rewrite module which you can [download here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). Another nice feature is that it can transform your outgoing html too.

More articles on how to use the IIS URL Rewrite Module: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module